# Java: how to disable mouse and keyboard system wide

Tags: java, hook, java-native-interface

Alright, I am not sure if this is even possible with Java specifically, but I am working on a a small program very similar to synergy and I need to be able to completely disable input from the mouse and keyboard on the host computer, but still record the input within the program.  I can not think of any clean and robust ways to do this with Java.  Is this possible?

Comment: You can use C++ to apply system level hook for keyboard and mouse, and do what ever you want. Then call these function in Java code through JNI.

Answer (score 1):

Any way you will have to use JNI for such a purpose.Have a look at this [blog](http://www.jotschi.de/?p=90) ,it will give you some idea.